# Disconnect from CRM Explorer - Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have installed CRM Developer Toolkit plugin for Visual Studio 2012.

I connected to an organization created at DEV server via CRM Explorer in Visual Studio 2012. Entities, Web Resources, and other artifacts are shown in this explorer.

I want to disconnect this CRM Explorer now. 
Though I can connect to another Server via Tools-->Connect to Dynamics CRM 2011 Server, but I cant remove it and want to keep it blank, ensuring accidental deployment doesn't happen.

Please let me know in case there is some way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I open the "Tools > Connect to Dynamics CRM Server..." menu option, clear any of the fields (usually I just swap http and https radio selections to auto clear), and try to connect, I lose my old connection.

The next time I open VS, it prompts me for the server connection details, though it is not necessary to restart VS in my experience.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I got the same from other forums. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me

-Tools > Connect to Dynamics CRM Server..." . Then you can log again to your dynamics crm server

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Visual Studio 2012 should disconnect any connected Organization in CRM Explorer. I just tried it on my dev machine and it when I opened the project again it gave me an error saying "No Organization has been specified".

So just save the solution and restart Visual Studio 2012.

Hope this helps.